# find the colour name from a hexadecimal colour code

Tags: python, image-processing

i want to find the name of a colour from the hexadecimal colour code. When i get a hex colour code i want to find the most matching colour name. for example for the code #c06040 , how to find out if it is a shade of brown, blue or yellow ?. so that i can find the colour of an object in the image without human intervention.

Is there any relation between the hexadecimal code of the shades of a colour?
please give some sample code if there is any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a program distributed with the Python source called *pynche* which can do this

The functionality you need is in the method `ColorDB.nearest()` in `ColorDB.py`

From Python/Tools/README

> ```
> Introduction
>
>     Pynche is a color editor based largely on a similar program that I
>     originally wrote back in 1987 for the Sunview window system.  That
>     editor was called ICE, the Interactive Color Editor.  I'd always
>     wanted to port this program to X but didn't feel like hacking X
>     and C code to do it.  Fast forward many years, to where Python +
>     Tkinter provides such a nice programming environment, with enough
>     power, that I finally buckled down and re-implemented it.  I
>     changed the name because these days, too many other systems have
>     the acronym `ICE'.
>
>     Pynche should work with any variant of Python after 1.5.2
>     (e.g. 2.0.1 and 2.1.1), using Tk 8.0.x.  It's been tested on
>     Solaris 2.6, Windows NT 4, and various Linux distros.  You'll want
>     to be sure to have at least Tk 8.0.3 for Windows.  Also, Pynche is
>     very colormap intensive, so it doesn't work very well on 8-bit
>     graphics cards; 24bit+ graphics cards are so cheap these days,
>     I'll probably never "fix" that.
>
>     Pynche must find a text database of colors names in order to
>     provide `nearest' color matching.  Pynche is distributed with an
>     rgb.txt file from the X11R6.4 distribution for this reason, along
>     with other "Web related" database (see below).  You can use a
>     different file with the -d option.  The file xlicense.txt contains
>     the license only for rgb.txt and both files are in the X/
>     subdirectory.
>
>     Pynche is pronounced: Pin'-chee
>
>
> Running Standalone
>
>     On Unix, start it by running the `pynche' script.  On Windows, run
>     pynche.pyw to inhibit the console window.  When run from the
>     command line, the following options are recognized:
>
>     --database file
>     -d file
>         Alternate location of the color database file.  Without this
>         option, the first valid file found will be used (see below).
>
>     --initfile file
>     -i file
>         Alternate location of the persistent initialization file.  See 
>         the section on Persistency below.
>
>     --ignore
>     -X
>         Ignore the persistent initialization file when starting up.
>         Pynche will still write the current option settings to the
>         persistent init file when it quits.
>
>     --help
>     -h
>         Print the help message.
>
>     initialcolor
>         a Tk color name or #rrggbb color spec to be used as the
>         initially selected color.  This overrides any color saved in
>         the persistent init file.  Since `#' needs to be escaped in
>         many shells, it is optional in the spec (e.g. #45dd1f is the
>         same as 45dd1f).
>
>
> Running as a Modal Dialog
>
>     Pynche can be run as a modal dialog, inside another application,
>     say as a general color chooser.  In fact, Grail 0.6 uses Pynche
>     and a future version of IDLE may as well.  Pynche supports the API
>     implemented by the Tkinter standard tkColorChooser module, with a
>     few changes as described below.  By importing pyColorChooser from
>     the Pynche package, you can run
>
>         pyColorChooser.askcolor()
>
>     which will popup Pynche as a modal dialog, and return the selected 
>     color.
>
>     There are some UI differences when running as a modal
>     vs. standalone.  When running as a modal, there is no "Quit" menu
>     item under the "File" menu.  Instead there are "Okay" and "Cancel"
>     buttons.
>
>     When "Okay" is hit, askcolor() returns the tuple
>
>         ((r, g, b), "name")
>
>     where r, g, and b are red, green, and blue color values
>     respectively (in the range 0 to 255).  "name" will be a color name
>     from the color database if there is an exact match, otherwise it
>     will be an X11 color spec of the form "#rrggbb".  Note that this
>     is different than tkColorChooser, which doesn't know anything
>     about color names.
>
>     askcolor() supports the following optional keyword arguments:
>
>         color
>             the color to set as the initial selected color
>
>         master[*]
>             the master window to use as the parent of the modal
>             dialog.  Without this argument, pyColorChooser will create 
>             its own Tkinter.Tk instance as the master.  This may not
>             be what you want.
>
>         databasefile
>             similar to the --database option, the value must be a
>             file name
>
>         initfile[*]
>             similar to the --initfile option, the value must be a
>             file name
>
>         ignore[*]
>             similar to the --ignore flag, the value is a boolean
>
>         wantspec
>             When this is true, the "name" field in the return tuple
>             will always be a color spec of the form "#rrggbb".  It
>             will not return a color name even if there is a match;
>             this is so pyColorChooser can exactly match the API of
>             tkColorChooser.
>
>         [*] these arguments must be specified the first time
>         askcolor() is used and cannot be changed on subsequent calls.
>
>
> The Colorstrip Window
>
>     The top part of the main Pynche window contains the "variation
>     strips".  Each strip contains a number of "color chips".  The
>     strips always indicate the currently selected color by a highlight
>     rectangle around the selected color chip, with an arrow pointing
>     to the chip.  Each arrow has an associated number giving you the
>     color value along the variation's axis.  Each variation strip
>     shows you the colors that are reachable from the selected color by
>     varying just one axis of the color solid.
>
>     For example, when the selected color is (in Red/Green/Blue
>     notation) 127/127/127, the Red Variations strip shows you every
>     color in the range 0/127/127 to 255/127/127.  Similarly for the
>     green and blue axes.  You can select any color by clicking on its
>     chip.  This will update the highlight rectangle and the arrow, as
>     well as other displays in Pynche.
>
>     Click on "Update while dragging" if you want Pynche to update the
>     selected color while you drag along any variation strip (this will
>     be a bit slower).  Click on "Hexadecimal" to display the arrow
>     numbers in hex.
>
>     There are also two shortcut buttons in this window, which
>     auto-select Black (0/0/0) and White (255/255/255).
>
>
> The Proof Window
>
>     In the lower left corner of the main window you see two larger
>     color chips.  The Selected chip shows you a larger version of the
>     color selected in the variation strips, along with its X11 color
>     specification.  The Nearest chip shows you the closest color in
>     the X11 database to the selected color, giving its X11 color
>     specification, and below that, its X11 color name.  When the
>     Selected chip color exactly matches the Nearest chip color, you
>     will see the color name appear below the color specification for
>     the Selected chip.
>
>     Clicking on the Nearest color chip selects that color.  Color
>     distance is calculated in the 3D space of the RGB color solid and
>     if more than one color name is the same distance from the selected
>     color, the first one found will be chosen.
>
>     Note that there may be more than one X11 color name for the same
>     RGB value.  In that case, the first one found in the text database
>     is designated the "primary" name, and this is shown under the
>     Nearest chip.  The other names are "aliases" and they are visible
>     in the Color List Window (see below).
>
>     Both the color specifications and color names are selectable for
>     copying and pasting into another window.
>
>
> The Type-in Window
>
>     At the lower right of the main window are three entry fields.
>     Here you can type numeric values for any of the three color axes.
>     Legal values are between 0 and 255, and these fields do not allow
>     you to enter illegal values.  You must hit Enter or Tab to select
>     the new color.
>
>     Click on "Update while typing" if you want Pynche to select the
>     color on every keystroke (well, every one that produces a legal
>     value!)  Click on "Hexadecimal" to display and enter color values
>     in hex.
>
>
> Other Views
>
>     There are three secondary windows which are not displayed by
>     default.  You can bring these up via the "View" menu on the main
>     Pynche window.
>
>
> The Text Window
>
>     The "Text Window" allows you to see what effects various colors
>     have on the standard Tk text widget elements.  In the upper part
>     of the window is a plain Tk text widget and here you can edit the
>     text, select a region of text, etc.  Below this is a button "Track
>     color changes".  When this is turned on, any colors selected in
>     the other windows will change the text widget element specified in
>     the radio buttons below.  When this is turned off, text widget
>     elements are not affected by color selection.
>
>     You can choose which element gets changed by color selection by
>     clicking on one of the radio buttons in the bottom part of this
>     window.  Text foreground and background affect the text in the
>     upper part of the window.  Selection foreground and background
>     affect the colors of the primary selection which is what you see
>     when you click the middle button (depending on window system) and
>     drag it through some text.
>
>     The Insertion is the insertion cursor in the text window, where
>     new text will be inserted as you type.  The insertion cursor only
>     has a background.
>
>
> The Color List Window
>
>     The "Color List" window shows every named color in the color name
>     database (this window may take a while to come up).  In the upper
>     part of the window you see a scrolling list of all the color names
>     in the database, in alphabetical order.  Click on any color to
>     select it.  In the bottom part of the window is displayed any
>     aliases for the selected color (those color names that have the
>     same RGB value, but were found later in the text database).  For
>     example, find the color "Black" and you'll see that its aliases
>     are "gray0" and "grey0".
>
>     If the color has no aliases you'll see "<no aliases>" here.  If you
>     just want to see if a color has an alias, and do not want to select a
>     color when you click on it, turn off "Update on Click".
>
>     Note that the color list is always updated when a color is selected
>     from the main window.  There's no way to turn this feature off.  If
>     the selected color has no matching color name you'll see
>     "<no matching color>" in the Aliases window.
>
>
> The Details Window
>
>     The "Details" window gives you more control over color selection
>     than just clicking on a color chip in the main window.  The row of
>     buttons along the top apply the specified increment and decrement
>     amounts to the selected color.  These delta amounts are applied to
>     the variation strips specified by the check boxes labeled "Move
>     Sliders".  Thus if just Red and Green are selected, hitting -10
>     will subtract 10 from the color value along the red and green
>     variation only.  Note the message under the checkboxes; this
>     indicates the primary color level being changed when more than one
>     slider is tied together.  For example, if Red and Green are
>     selected, you will be changing the Yellow level of the selected
>     color.
>
>     The "At Boundary" behavior determines what happens when any color
>     variation hits either the lower or upper boundaries (0 or 255) as
>     a result of clicking on the top row buttons:
>
>     Stop
>         When the increment or decrement would send any of the tied
>         variations out of bounds, the entire delta is discarded.
>
>     Wrap Around
>         When the increment or decrement would send any of the tied
>         variations out of bounds, the out of bounds value is wrapped
>         around to the other side.  Thus if red were at 238 and +25
>         were clicked, red would have the value 7.
>
>     Preserve Distance
>         When the increment or decrement would send any of the tied
>         variations out of bounds, all tied variations are wrapped as
>         one, so as to preserve the distance between them.  Thus if
>         green and blue were tied, and green was at 238 while blue was
>         at 223, and +25 were clicked, green would be at 15 and blue
>         would be at 0.
>
>     Squash
>         When the increment or decrement would send any of the tied
>         variations out of bounds, the out of bounds variation is set
>         to the ceiling of 255 or floor of 0, as appropriate.  In this
>         way, all tied variations are squashed to one edge or the
>         other.
>
>     The top row buttons have the following keyboard accelerators:
>
>     -25 == Shift Left Arrow
>     -10 == Control Left Arrow
>      -1 == Left Arrow
>      +1 == Right Arrow
>     +10 == Control Right Arrow
>     +25 == Shift Right Arrow
>
>
> Keyboard Accelerators
>
>     Alt-w in any secondary window dismisses the window.  In the main
>     window it exits Pynche (except when running as a modal).
>
>     Alt-q in any window exits Pynche (except when running as a modal).
>
>
> Persistency
>
>     Pynche remembers various settings of options and colors between
>     invocations, storing these values in a `persistent initialization
>     file'.  The actual location of this file is specified by the
>     --initfile option (see above), and defaults to ~/.pynche.
>
>     When Pynche exits, it saves these values in the init file, and
>     re-reads them when it starts up.  There is no locking on this
>     file, so if you run multiple instances of Pynche at a time, you
>     may clobber the init file.
>
>     The actual options stored include
>
>     - the currently selected color
>
>     - all settings of checkbox and radio button options in all windows
>
>     - the contents of the text window, the current text selection and
>       insertion point, and all current text widget element color
>       settings.
>
>     - the name of the color database file (but not its contents)
>
>     You can inhibit Pynche from reading the init file by supplying the
>     --ignore option on the command line.  However, you cannot suppress
>     the storing of the settings in the init file on Pynche exit.  If
>     you really want to do this, use /dev/null as the init file, using
>     --initfile.
>
>
> Color Name Database Files
>
>     Pynche uses a color name database file to calculate the nearest
>     color to the selected color, and to display in the Color List
>     view.  Several files are distributed with Pynche, described
>     below.  By default, the X11 color name database file is selected.
>     Other files:
>
>     html40colors.txt -- the HTML 4.0 guaranteed color names
>
>     websafe.txt -- the 216 "Web-safe" colors that Netscape and MSIE
>     guarantee will not be dithered.  These are specified in #rrggbb
>     format for both values and names
>
>     webcolors.txt -- The 140 color names that Tim Peters and his
>     sister say NS and MSIE both understand (with some controversy over 
>     AliceBlue).
>
>     namedcolors.txt -- an alternative set of Netscape colors.
>
>     You can switch between files by choosing "Load palette..." from
>     the "File" menu.  This brings up a standard Tk file dialog.
>     Choose the file you want and then click "Ok".  If Pynche
>     understands the format in this file, it will load the database and 
>     update the appropriate windows.  If not, it will bring up an error 
>     dialog.
>
>
> To Do
>
>     Here's a brief list of things I want to do (some mythical day):
>
>     - Better support for resizing the top level windows
>
>     - More output views, e.g. color solids
>
>     - Have the notion of a `last color selected'; this may require a
>       new output view
>
>     - Support setting the font in the text view
>
>     - Support distutils setup.py for installation
>
>     I'm open to suggestions!
>
>
>
>
> Local Variables:
> indent-tabs-mode: nil
> End:
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Hexadecimal web colour values are just a form of RGB. Convert your RGB values to [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), and then partition the Hue space into the different colours.

For example, a Hue value of about 0-19 would be "red", 20-39 "orange", 40-59 "yellow", etc. (These numbers are not exact, I just had a quick glance at the Hue chart on the Wikipedia page.)

For a more complex analysis of the colour name, use the Lightness value also. For example, "brown" is just a darker yellow.

Comment: +1 -- I got into this at one point a while back, but couldn't even remember the acronym. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can build `dict` of hex codes as keys and human readable color names as values.

Here is a *heuristic/fuzzy* function for guessing  **what a color might look like** ;)

```
colorof = {'f0f8ff':"Alice Blue",
           'faebd7':"Antique White",
           '000000':"Black"}

def get_color_name(hx):
    # if color is found in dict
    if colorof.has_key(hx):return colorof[hx]

    # else return its closest available color
    m = 16777215
    k = '000000'
    for key in colorof.keys():
        a = int(hx[:2],16)-int(key[:2],16)
        b = int(hx[2:4],16)-int(key[2:4],16)
        c = int(hx[4:],16)-int(key[4:],16)

        v = a*a+b*b+c*c # simple measure for distance between colors

        # v = (r1 - r2)^2 + (g1 - g2)^2 + (b1 - b2)^2

        if v <= m:
            m = v
            k = key

    return colorof[k]

print get_color_name('f0f8ff') # found in dict
print get_color_name('faeb11') # closest to Antique white
```

Comment: That's going to be a large dict. `{'000000': 'black', '000001': 'still pitch black, with a hint of blue blackness', '000002': 'nope, still rather black', ...}`

Comment: +1 Ya its going to have 16^6 keys but we could do with around 100 keys and some measure for closeness of color. See updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: @TMC: What's the problem? 16^6 is only 22 in the Python neck of the woods :-)

Comment: There is problem with the distance measure `00ffff` and `ffff00` will be the same same color according to it! but looking athttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names should work fine practically

Comment: You should use different color distance function, called delta_e. It is in colormath library.

Comment: You don't have a name for each possible hex, you have a hex for each standard color name. HTML/CSS defines only 147 names/hex values. (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example I have written, which uses the pearson coefficient to compare two colors and chooses the most similar color from a dict. This solution is probably not the most efficient one, but the results should be quite good:

```
import re
re_color = re.compile('#([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})')
from math import sqrt

def color_to_rgb(color):
    return tuple(int(x, 16) / 255.0 for x in re_color.match(color).groups())

def similarity(color1, color2):
    """Computes the pearson correlation coefficient for two colors. The result
    will be between 1.0 (very similar) and -1.0 (no similarity)."""
    c1 = color_to_rgb(color1)
    c2 = color_to_rgb(color2)

    s1 = sum(c1)
    s2 = sum(c2)
    sp1 = sum(map(lambda c: pow(c, 2), c1))
    sp2 = sum(map(lambda c: pow(c, 2), c2))
    sp = sum(map(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], zip(c1, c2)))

    return (sp - (s1 * s2 / 3.0)) / sqrt((sp1 - pow(s1, 2) / 3.0) * (sp2 - pow(s2, 2) / 3.0))

color_names = {
    '#ff0000': 'red',
    '#00ff00': 'green',
    '#0000ff': 'blue'
    # add more color definitions here
}

def find_name(color):
    sim = [(similarity(color, c), name) for c, name in color_names.items()]
    return max(sim, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]

print find_name('#cc0000') # returns "red"
```

Comment: i've added many colors, but your code excepts on gray variants (e.g.  '#000000': 'black', '#696969': 'dim gray', '#808080': 'gray' etc.)

Comment: Could you please explain how Pearson coefficient measures the similarity in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is precious @tux21b, but it fails with more color_names and non really approaching web-color value.
It crashes with a Divide by Zero Error on this line :

```py
return (sp - (s1 * s2 / 3.0)) / sqrt((sp1 - pow(s1, 2) / 3.0) * (sp2 - pow(s2, 2) / 3.0))
```

I'm not a good mathematician, but I was thinking that, if the *similarity* function returns a value from -1 (not similar) to +1 (exact color), then if a divide by zero occured, it should return 0 ?
So I've fixed your code like this :

```py
        try:
            computed = (sp - (s1 * s2 / 3.0)) / sqrt((sp1 - pow(s1, 2) / 3.0) * (sp2 - pow(s2, 2) / 3.0))
        except:
            computed = 0
    
        return computed
```

Then, it works well and returns the good approaching values, even with a larger set of predefined colors like this:

```py
color_names = {
    '#000000': 'black',
    '#ffffff': 'white',
    '#808080': 'dark gray',
    '#b0b0b0': 'light gray',
    '#ff0000': 'red',
    '#800000': 'dark red',
    '#00ff00': 'green',
    '#008000': 'darkgreen',
    '#0000ff': 'blue',
    '#000080': 'dark blue',
    '#ffff00': 'yellow',
    '#808000': 'olive',
    '#00ffff': 'cyan',
    '#ff00ff': 'magenta',
    '#800080': 'purple'
    }
```

Comment: Just for anyone who wants to try it. The code still doesn't work. Put red in the first line and search for black, it will return red. 
print(dc.find_name('#cc0000')) # returns "red"
print(dc.find_name('#000000')) -> returns red
print(dc.find_name('#ffffff')) -> returns red

Comment: the issue happens for all colors where all three values are the same in r,g,b. 000000, ffffff, 808080, ... because similarity function as well as numpy and other implementations have to divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia page for web colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) has quite a lot of them listed, as does [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp) and the temptingly-named [html-color-names.com](http://www.html-color-names.com/color-chart.php). :-) And [this guy](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1colors.htm) has a seriously thorough page about color generally, and color on computers and the web specifically. You could visit them, search for your color code, and see if it's listed (and if not, look for close ones).

**Edit** I missed the Python tag. If you want to do this from code, the above may not be 100% useful. You *could* build a pretty good associative lookup based on information from sites like that, but even with color names being somewhat subjective, it seems like there's probably a good algorithmic approach out there.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) on Wikipedia provides an example of lookup from name to hex codes.  It would be fairly easy to lookup in the other direction.  Whether there is a relationship between codes and names that suits you is up to you.  You'll probably find other color-name code tables too.