# Convert RGB color to English color name, like 'green' with Python

Tags: python, css, image, colors, tuples

I want to convert a color tuple to a color name, like 'yellow' or 'blue'

```
>>> im = Image.open("test.jpg")
>>> n, color = max(im.getcolors(im.size[0]*im.size[1]))
>>> print color
(119, 172, 152)
```

Is there a simple way in python to do this?

Comment: I think I found the droids you're looking for... http://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/1.3#conversions-from-integer-rgb-triplets

Comment: I don't know if there's already a solution to this, but any such mapping will necessarily be heuristic and entirely subjective... Interesting question, though!

Comment: Do you want _precise_ colour names or approximations? For example, "green" is (obviously) `(0,255,0)`. What would you like `color((0,254,0))` to be?

Comment: @WillVousden not necessarily: some colours have official names.

Comment: Do you want the colors to be the same colors that are used when setting a font color in HTML (e.g., `<font color = "red">Sample text</font>`)?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It looks like [webcolors](https://pypi.org/project/webcolors/) will allow you to do this:

> rgb_to_name(rgb_triplet, spec='css3')
>
> Convert a 3-tuple of integers, suitable for use in an rgb() color triplet, to its corresponding normalized color name, if any such name exists; valid values are html4, css2, css21 and css3, and the default is css3.

> Example:

```
>>> rgb_to_name((0, 0, 0))
'black'
```

it is vice-versa-able:

```
>>> name_to_rgb('navy')
(0, 0, 128)
```

#To find the closest colour name:

However `webcolors` raises an exception if it can't find a match for the requested colour. I've written a little fix that delivers the closest matching name for the requested RGB colour. It matches by Euclidian distance in the RGB space.

```
import webcolors

def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
    try:
        closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
    except ValueError:
        closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
        actual_name = None
    return actual_name, closest_name

requested_colour = (119, 172, 152)
actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(requested_colour)

print("Actual colour name:", actual_name, ", closest colour name:", closest_name)
```

Output:

```
Actual colour name: None , closest colour name: cadetblue
```

Comment: It doesn't work for all RGB combinations like:
print(webcolors.rgb_to_name((231, 201, 186)))
throws error i.e. "ValueError: '#e7c9ba' has no defined color name in css3"

Comment: @Asim, it looks like this code is for an earlier (probably Py2) version.  For webcolors-1.11.1, you need to replace ```for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():``` with ```for name, key in webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():```.  Then the rest of the code (aside from the print statement which just needs to be f-stringed and wrapped in parentheses) should work.

Comment: @AndrewStewart `for key, name in webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():` worked for me with webcolors-1.11.1. I switched `key` and `name`.

Answer (score 12):

There is a program called pynche which can change RGB to colour name in English for Python.

You can try to use the method `ColorDB.nearest()` in `ColorDB.py` which can do what you want.

You can find more information about this method here : [ColorDB Pynche](http://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.2.2/namespacepynche_1_1ColorDB.html#ab04671662b58e603cdfaeea312496541)

Comment: Provided link doesn't work anymore. Here you can find file [ColorDB.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/pynche/ColorDB.py).

Comment: For anyone in the future viewing this post, here is a modified version of ColorDB.py I modified for python3: https://github.com/EricPanDev/python3-colordb/blob/main/ColorDB.py

Answer (score 12):

For those who, like me, want a more familiar colour name, you can use the [CSS 2.1 colour names](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/webcolors/src/b93975d4507fbf0a500656cb475dbd8ddae7a549/webcolors.py?at=default#cl-166), also provided by `webcolors`:

- aqua: `#00ffff`
- black: `#000000`
- blue: `#0000ff`
- fuchsia: `#ff00ff`
- green: `#008000`
- grey: `#808080`
- lime: `#00ff00`
- maroon: `#800000`
- navy: `#000080`
- olive: `#808000`
- purple: `#800080`
- red: `#ff0000`
- silver: `#c0c0c0`
- teal: `#008080`
- white: `#ffffff`
- yellow: `#ffff00`
- orange: `#ffa500`

Just use fraxel's excellent answer and code for getting the closest colour, adapted to CSS 2.1:

```
def get_colour_name(rgb_triplet):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.css21_hex_to_names.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - rgb_triplet[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - rgb_triplet[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - rgb_triplet[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]
```

Comment: You can have a greater accuracy using the CSS4 list, which is provided by `matplotlib.colors`. For example `import matplotlib.colors as mc` and `mycss4list = mc.CSS4_COLORS`

Comment: I had to use the constant CSS21_HEX_TO_NAMES (uppercase) to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

A solution to your problem consists in mapping the RGB values to the HSL color space.

Once you have the color in the HSL color space you can use the H (hue) component to map it the color. Note that color is a somewhat subjective concept, so you would have to define which ranges of H corresponds to a given color.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a dictionary to figure out the base colors, and then find the closest one.:

```
def get_color_name(rgb):
colors = {
    "red": (255, 0, 0),
    "green": (0, 255, 0),
    "blue": (0, 0, 255),
    "yellow": (255, 255, 0),
    "magenta": (255, 0, 255),
    "cyan": (0, 255, 255),
    "black": (0, 0, 0),
    "white": (255, 255, 255)
}
min_distance = float("inf")
closest_color = None
for color, value in colors.items():
    distance = sum([(i - j) ** 2 for i, j in zip(rgb, value)])
    if distance < min_distance:
        min_distance = distance
        closest_color = color
return closest_color

# Testing
print(get_color_name((255, 0, 0)))  # red
print(get_color_name((0, 255, 0)))  # green
print(get_color_name((0, 0, 255)))  # blue
```

Comment: Not working. Try (0,5,0), which is dark green. Your script says it's gray

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found to solve this problem is the one provided by tux21b on this post:
[find the colour name from a hexadecimal colour code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453344/find-the-colour-name-from-a-hexadecimal-colour-code/65074672#65074672)
With the fix I've made (to avoid the division by zero error).
It is (from my understanding) an approximation calculation, that doesn't require to load a large set of data table to get an approaching value, and that allow to set your own set of needed colors.